# CakePHP jSon format change

Tags: json, cakephp-2.0, response, output

I'm finding list of `Areas` for my `CakePHP 2.x` website and it supports, `JSON` output as below with `find all` method:

```
$this->Area->find('all', array('fields' => array('id', 'name', 'order'), 'conditions' => array('Area.status' => 1)));
```

Below is my JSON output:

```
[{"Area":{"id":"2","name":"Area 1","order":"1"}},{"Area":{"id":"3","name":"Area 2","order":"1"}}]
```

Now Is that possible for me to remove `Area` tag which is repeating everytime?

Any patch for same? Do let me know if any suggestions / ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP Provides some in-built library functions for data extraction from result set and output same as `JSON` format.

```
    // initialize your function to render false and response type json
    $this->autoRender = false; // no view to render
    $this->response->type('json');

    // Remove Area from array and encode
    $area = Set::extract('/Area/.', $area);
    $json = json_encode( $area);
    $this->response->body($json);
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

on your view for output json write this:

```
echo json_encode(Set::extract('/Area/.', $area));
```

For me works fine.